# How can I save all the coordinates on which a person has moved to a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

### Heading

> There is a man which is trying to move inside a square board. The board is a grid of size  where the point  is in its upper-left corner and the point  is in its bottom-right corner. The man will move only by following some rules:
>
> It will always move according to the current direction of the wind (possible directions are North, South, West, East, North-East, North-West, South-East, South-West).
>   It can visit a specific cell of the board only once.
>   It can not go out of the borders of the board.
>   If it reaches at a point where it can not move according to the rules, it will stay at the current position.
>   It can move only to the neighbouring cells (8 possible moves according to the above directions).
>   It will always start its journey from the point  (the upper-left corner of the board).
>   It can only make one movement per second.
>   In order to make things more difficult for him, the wind will change its direction multiple times during the man's journey. You will always be given the direction of the wind before the man starts to move (0-th second) and then you will be given the specific time in seconds when the wind is going to change its direction (in a strictly increasing sequence).
>
> After following all the journey of the man, you will have to specify how many positions inside the board were not visited by the man.
>
> Input Format
>
> In the first line you will be given two integers 'n' and 'k' where 'n' represents the dimension of the board. Then in the following 'k' lines you will be given an integer 'ti' and a string 'w'. The 'ti'  represents the time in seconds in which on the board a wind of direction 'w' will be applied.The 'w' might take a value of N, S, W, E, NE, NW, SE, or SW (representing North, South, West, East, North-East, North-West, South-East or South-West, respectively).
>
> Constraints
>
> 3 <= n <= 100000
>
> 2 <= k <= 100000
>
> 0 <= ti <=100000
>
> t0 = 0 < t1 <...< tk-1
>
> Output Format
>
> Output the number of positions inside the board that were not visited by the man.
>
> Sample Input 0
>
> 5 6
>
> 0 SE
>
> 1 NE
>
> 2 E
>
> 6 SW
>
> 15 N
>
> 20 W
>
> Sample Output 0
>
> 13

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main (String args []) {

        //Table
        int [][] board = new int [7][7]; 

        // Seconds available for moving
        int seconds = 43; 
        // Initial Man Coordinate
        int Man = board [0][0]; 

        // Two dimensional array to save the coordinates visited by the man
        int [][] isVisited = new int [7][7]; 

        // Formula to calculate the cells that are not visited by the man ( i know is wrong )
        int notVisited = isVisited.isEmpty(true) - isVisited.isEmpty(false);  

        for (int i=0;i<=board.length;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<=board.length;j--) {

                while (seconds < 4 ) {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                    Man = board [i][j];

                    //Here should be the code to save the coordinates visited by the man -->
```

Comment: Just iterate over your `isVisited` array with a nested for loop and count the number of times the value is `true`

Comment: Please elaborate what this array is supposed to store

Comment: Type of isVisited should be boolean, not int btw.

Comment: @MWB is there any way to ''connect'' the exact same way of the man move in board [ ][ ] into the isVisited [ ][ ] ? A smart short way i mean

Comment: @Minn the board [ ] [ ] isn't storing anything,is just playing the role of a path where man can move. The isVisited [ ] [  ] should save tha coordinates of cells that man visited. In the end I should return the number of cells that man doesn't visited

Comment: @maio290 i declare that like int becouse i want to save the coordinates of cells visited by the man,maybe i choosed the wrong way to save the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

I would first create a new call called `Board`:

```
public class Board {
    private boolean[][] visited;
    private int boardSize;
    private int numVisited;

    public Board(int boardSize) {
        this.boardSize = boardSize;
        visited = new boolean[boardSize][boardSize];
    }

    public void setVisited(int x, int y) {
        if (!visited[x][y]) {
            visited[x][y] = true;
            numVisited++;
        }
    }

    public int getBoardSize() {
        return boardSize;
    }

    public int getNumVisited() {
        return numVisited;
    }

    public int getNumNotVisited() {
        return boardSize * boardSize - numVisited;
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can create an instance of `Board`

```
Board myBoard = new Board(7);
```

And then in your logic, you can set a cell to visited by calling `setVisited`:

```
myBoard.setVisited(3, 3);
```

And you can count the number of visited cells by calling `countVisited`

```
int numberOfVisitedCells = myBoard.getNumVisited();
```

Or, if you want the number of cells that have not been visited:

```
int numberofCellsNotVisited = myBoard.getNumNotVisited();
```

EDIT: Thanks @Matthew for the improvement!

Comment: I'd have `numVisited` increment on a new visit rather than looping through the board each time they need to get the amount of spaces  visited.

Comment: Great suggestion!

Comment: @MWB Type mismatch: cannot convert from Board[][] to boolean[][]

Comment: @OltiQosja. Not sure what you are trying to do, but you do not need a `Board[][]`. That would be a two-dimensional array of `Boards`, which are in turn two-dimensional arrays of `boolean`s...

Comment: @MWB i understand your logic but it seems java don't want to do that in that way :p I'm getting error of that declaration

Comment: @OltiQosja: Sorry, contained a small mistake which I fixed!

Comment: @MWB so if i have 10 coordinates of the man movemant i should set them like : myBoard.setVisited(3, 3); myBoard.setVisited(2,1) ; etc ? you think this is the best way? and in the end creating and calling the numberofCellsNotVisited() method to display the number?

Comment: That is what I would do.

Comment: @MWB can you please give me your email so i can explain better what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: @Perthupuethto do you still need help with this?

Comment: @Matthew the real problem is more complicated than that i had asked here ,that's why

Comment: @Perthupuethto Do you have documentation for your requirements? Could those be posted?

Comment: @Perthupuethto I went ahead and made my own solution without conforming to the input. I just threw it in github for you. https://github.com/Matime/ManInTheSand

Comment: @Matthew when I run the project the output is 5435476. Anyway the time should be as  the requirements not random and in the direction should be North-East, North-West, South-East, South-West as well. As advice think the movement of the men like the snake game.

Comment: @Perthupuethto I was creating that to demonstrate how I would go about saving the coordinates saved by the man and displaying the amount of coordinates that have not been visited by the man. The program does handle North-East, North-West, South-East, and South-West.

Comment: @Matthew I forgot the enum sorry. Anyway thank you man , i really appreciate it. I would like to mark your answer as ''solved'' :p